# Gnome Maps not working properly

Tags: release-loki, apps

The map is loading, I can zoom in and out, but I can't go to any location that I search for in the search bar. If I click on the location in the search results nothing happens. Do I have to install something additional? I've booted Ubuntu Gnome from an USB and Maps works there.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a couple of years old but.  I had the same issue in Ubuntu and found this solution.  After setting this up (I had to install gsconnect to connect my phone to gnome which I had done anyways).  Installing Geoclue Share on my phone made gnome maps magically just start working.

https://www.freeyourdesktop.com/2018/09/improve-gnome-maps-location-accuracy-with-your-android-phone/